Docker windows container issue with Encrypting File System (EFS)
I'm having issues running tests on a docker container. (Windows 10 host, windows 10 guest).
Host: Win10 22H2   OS Build 19045.4170. Docker v4.25.0.
docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/windows:20H2-KB5013942-amd64
Within the container we run following commands.
mkdir foo
cipher /e foo
cd foo
echo "hello" > test.txt

During the last command, following error is reported: Access is denied. Without the preceding cipher command, the test.txt file gets created. Cipher is a windows application that encrypts files/directories by using Encrypting File System (EFS). Our tests are making use of EFS technology (EncryptFile / WriteFile win32 API) that encounter the same issue.
The docker user running the commands is administrator, so I don't understand where the access is denied comes from.
I tried running the same commands on my host windows, there the commands succeeded.
